# Unable to get Restart and apply changes in Jmeter when I download plugins from Plugin Manager

Tags: jmeter-plugins

when I download the custom thread group in the Jmeter plugin manager I am unable to see the 'restart and apply changes' button.

I am expecting how to get restart and apply button for Jmeter in plugin manger option.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 options:

1. Plugins download fails somewhere somehow (you're behind a proxy, your company is using a MITM certificate, you're not connected to the Internet,etc.). Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), get the root cause of the problem and fix it.
2. The Plugins Manager window doesn't fit into your screen. In that case you need to either [decrease zoom level](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-custom-display-scaling-setting-windows-10) of your operating system or [resize the window](https://winaero.com/how-to-resize-a-window-using-keyboard-only-in-windows-10-and-other-versions/) so it won't be that big or invest into higher-resolution display.

   [image]

More information: [How to Install the JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)